# Touch action prevents click events

Tags: javascript, css

i have a div that has `touch-action:pan-y;`
that div is surronded by an anchor tag.

now if you click on that div the link will work and you will be redirected.

But, if i swipe on the div and release the swipe and then click on the div, the link won't work on the first click, but on the second it will work.

so it turns out that all click event handlers won't fire on the first click after swipe has been done.

how do i solve this issue without messing things up with SEO and Crawlers.

i need touch-action:pan-y because it allows me to block scrolling vertically when the user swipe the div horizontally but drawback is that now i need to click twice after swipe in order that the link will work.

any solution that won't cause trouble with SEO?

Answer (score 0):

```
How about you;
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var link = document.getElementById('myLink');

var isSwiping = false;

div.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  isSwiping = false;
});

div.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  isSwiping = true;
});

div.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  if (!isSwiping) {
    link.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly the idea that came to my mind. 
but i'm afraid that the Web Crawler will find this suspicious or that it won't index the link